# V→vii° or vii°→V

Tags: chord-progressions

I have been taught that V→vii° is a better harmonic progression since vii° forms a diminished fifth so it sounds more intensive than V. However, I saw some online lessons suggests that vii°→V is more commonly used because V has stronger tendency to I. I also found some composers say V →vii° and vii° to V are both acceptable in tonal harmony. Now I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 6):

Ignore all that noise about "better" or "worse."  It's all nonsense.  Both chords have been used extensively throughout music since the Baroque.  You don't have to window shop to find the best model.

You have to decide what you want your voices to do in that cadential moment.  If you want to hear a nice bass jump, use a V chord.  If you'd like a denser stepwise motion, use the dim vii.

Think of these as flavors of related chords.

- a dim chord is basically a V7 missing the root.  You should feel free to add or omit that note whenever you want.
- a V7 is a dim 7 chord, but with one note lowered to make it fit a V-I cadence.

VERY important is to understand that there are only 3 diminished 7th chords, and that lowering ANY note on ANY dim 7th chord will give you a V7 in the key of *something*.

Comment: In the second paragraph you consider what is the role of the root of the V chord, but can you expand about the 7th? In V-viio the 7th of V can resolve directly onto the tonic chord, in viio-V it doesn't. What does it change?

Comment: Hi, I agree that V and vii° have been used but my original question is how these chords connected.

Comment: The 5th of a vii° *is* the "7th of V."  Same note, same treatment (it falls to the 3rd of the tonic).  A vii° triad is a V7 with the root missing.  Therefore, everything will resolve by step.  If you want your bass to leap, then you use a V chord, otherwise, you can use a vii°7 or an inversion of V7.

Comment: @Te Wei Huang  The chords are connected by 2 common notes, including the leading tone, which makes them both suitable to lead to the tonic chord.  The vii° also has the 4th of a key, which falls to the 3rd of the tonic chord.  So does a V7.  The V7 is a vii° triad with the V added.  You should play all these chords on the piano and see for yourself how they are related.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973  Of course I know both V7 and vii° can be resolved to tonic chord. I'm just wondering is vii° to V7 more used than V to vii° because I read two contradictory theories.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Do you think vii° to V (not vii° to V7) is a good progression? I think that's the question he wants to ask. From my point of view that's a possible explanation why vii° to V (not V7) is not satisfactory because the tendency tone always need to be resolved.

Comment: The two chords alone aren't really a progression at all, as they are so closely related.  Unless you have some bigger context (like a series of movements by 3rds, or some melodic device that you want to bring out), you can interchange them as much as you like.  You don't need to worry about a "tendency tone" when you are essentially moving to another inversion / version of the same chord.  If you did, nobody could play arpeggios, ever.

Answer (score 1):

Kostka says "If vii° and V are used next to each other, V will usually follow the vii° because the V is the strongest sound." He suggests vii° to V is the better harmonic progression.

Comment: Hi! If you want to respond to someone's answer, the best way is to click "Add a comment." If you use "Your answer," it means you're answering the main question that you posted at the top. Do you think you could edit your original question to quote what Kostka says? I have a feeling there's context that matters.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I think this use of answering your own question is legitimate - it's quite likely that the OP is satisfied with this answer.

Comment: "Usually" and "better" are not the same thing.  If you go through life choosing to limit your cadential treatments with this rule, you will be needlessly reducing your ability to express yourself musically.